# How to prove a set is well-ordered

Tags: order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

This is the question I am struggling with. I understand what well-ordering is - a totally ordered set with a smallest element. I just cannot see how to actually show these two properties.

Q: Let $F$ is a set of well-ordered subsets of some partially ordered set, such that for every pair
$C, C’ \in F$ either $C$ is an initial segment of $C’$, or $C’$ is an initial segment of $C$ 
If I let $U:= \cup_{C \in F} C$

How do I show $U$ is in fact well-ordered and also that $C$ is an initial segment of $U$?

I have no idea how to approach this so a direction of where to go is what I ask.

Comment: What you wrote isn't quite correct.  A well ordered set is not a totally ordered set with a smallest element.  A well ordered set is a totally ordered set in which every non-empty subset has a smallest element.  The interval $[0, 1] \subseteq \Bbb R$ with the usual ordering has a smallest element but is not well ordered because (among other reasons) the subset $(0, 1)$ has no smallest element.

Comment: What about the well-ordering axiom?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What about it?  To show that $U$ is well ordered, assume $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq U$.  You need to prove that $A$ has a least element.  Start by noting that $\exists x \in A$, so $x \in C \in F$ for some $C$.  Now consider $A \cap C$.

Comment: Does WO not imply the real numbers ARE well-ordered?

Comment: Not under the usual ordering.  By the well-ordering axiom I suspect you mean the axiom (equivalent to the Axiom of Choice) that any set can be well ordered.  But in the case of $\Bbb R$, the ordering that results in a well ordering is very much not the usual order.  Just note that under the usual ordering, $\Bbb R$ has no least element.

Comment: That is what I meant, thanks.

Comment: @Anteater23 A classic example is $\mathbb Z$. Under its standard ordering, it is not well-ordered, but under the ordering $$0<1<-1<2<-2<...$$It is in fact, well-ordered.

Comment: I’m not sure why we can consider AnC. This obviously is a subset of C but AnC doesn’t necessarily belong to F in which case it doesn’t necessarily have a smallest element?

Comment: @Anteater23 $C$ is well ordered, and $A\cap C\subset C$.

Comment: And therefore AnC is totally ordered? We can’t be sure the minimal element in C is also in AnC?

Comment: @Anteater23 Can you write down the definition of well-ordering again?

Comment: I forgot about it meaning SUBSET has minimal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well-ordered set $X$ is a set where every non-empty $S\subset X$ has a minimal element. The well-ordering axiom says that given any set $X$, there exists a total ordering on the set which is a well-ordering.

Suppose $U=\bigcup F$ isn't well ordered. That implies that there exists some $V\subset U$ such that $x\in V$ but $V$ has no minimal element.

Note that $x\in C$ for some $C\in F$ by the definition of $U$. So, consider $C\cap V\subset C$. Since this set is non-empty and $C$ is well-ordered, we know that there exists $y$ minimal element in $C\cap V$.

Since $V$ is not well-ordered, there exists $z\in V$ such that $z<y$. So, $z\notin C$. Let $C'\in F$ such that $z\in C'$. Note that $C$ is an initial segment for $C'$ since $C'\not\subset C$.

This is a contradiction since $C$ contains $y$, but doesn't contain $z<y$. That means $C$ can't be an initial segment of $C'$.

Hence, $U$ is well-ordered. The remainder of the proof is quite trivial.